# PIVOT Not Working on a DENSE_RANK Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm writing a report which gives weekly totals for daily operational data. There will be 8 weeks across the top of the report as columns. Each row is a vehicle. Variables such as date range will be made dynamic eventually, this is a little more hard coded right now whilst I develop it. The 8 weeks can remain hard coded.

This works perfectly:

```
SELECT vehicle, [2] AS W2, [3] AS W3, [4] AS W4, [5] AS W5, [6] AS W6, [7] AS W7, [8] AS W8, [9] AS W9
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        Vehicle
        ,datepart(week,recordedoneffective) as WeekNum
        ,sum(totalweight ) AS TotalWeight
    from vw_visit_details v, vw_food_stats f
    where v.VisitId = f.VisitId
    and recordedoneffective between '2015-01-05' and '2015-03-01'
    group by vehicle,datepart(week,recordedoneffective)
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(TotalWeight) 
    FOR WeekNum IN ([2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])
    ) pvt
ORDER BY pvt.vehicle
```

Results:

```
Vehicle             W2      W3      W4      W5      W6      W7      W8      W9
Apples - D44CW      2603    7840    3200    1540    3516    2828    3217    3911
Bananas - 664SEC    4063    5004    5935    8734    8333    8663    4591    7807
Capsicum - YPD094   4699    6191    6423    4560    5742    7004    7204    5347
```

However since WeekNum varies depending on the date specified, I wanted to transform the WeekNum into a rank, which would remain static all the time. To do this I used DENSE_RANK so transform a range of 8 week numbers (2-9 in this case) into the numbers 1-8.

```
SELECT vehicle, [1] AS W1, [2] AS W2, [3] AS W3, [4] AS W4, [5] AS W5, [6] AS W6, [7] AS W7, [8] AS W8
FROM
(
        select 
        Vehicle
        ,datepart(week,recordedoneffective) as WeekNum
        ,dense_rank() OVER ( ORDER BY datepart    (week,recordedoneffective) ) AS WeekSeq
        ,sum(totalweight ) AS TotalWeight
    from vw_visit_details v, vw_food_stats f
    where v.VisitId = f.VisitId
    and recordedoneffective between '2015-01-05' and '2015-03-01'
    group by vehicle,   datepart(week,recordedoneffective)
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(TotalWeight) 
    FOR WeekSeq IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])
    ) pvt
ORDER BY pvt.vehicle
```

Note that the column names are now 1-8 rather than 2-9 and the pivot column has changed. However now the rest set is not correctly pivoted.

```
Vehicle         W1      W2      W3      W4      W5      W6      W7      W8
Apples - D44CW  2603    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Apples - D44CW  NULL    7840    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Apples - D44CW  NULL    NULL    3200    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Apples - D44CW  NULL    NULL    NULL    1540    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Apples - D44CW  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3516    NULL    NULL    NULL
Apples - D44CW  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2828    NULL    NULL
Apples - D44CW  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3217    NULL
Apples - D44CW  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3911
Bananas - 664SEC    4063    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

So basically, the pivot is not pivoting any more. The inner `src` result set for both queries are exactly the same (other than the addition of the new column) - the same number of results are returned, no new nulls, etc.

Thought maybe I'd need to `GROUP BY` the `dense_rank() OVER ( ORDER BY datepart(week,recordedoneffective) )` column, but you can't group by that. Also thought I should try removing the `datepart(week,recordedoneffective)` calculated col now that is not used - turns out it is still essential to have it there in order to use it in the `OVER` clause.

Why is this pivot not working? Presumably I can work around the problem with more dynamic SQL, but I see no reason why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CTE has four columns: Vehicle, WeekNum, WeekSeq, and TotalWeight.  The PIVOT clause references the last two; this means that the implicit grouping of the pivot is based on the first two columns.  So you get one row for each unique combination of Vehicle and WeekNum.  This is not clear in your result set because you aren't selecting WeekNum.

In your case, the answer is simple - remove WeekNum from the CTE, as you aren't actually using it.

Comment: Thanks, this explains the reasoning I hadn't yet got from @Hart CO's answer. However I did try and remove the col but couldn't due to syntax reasons (so its not quite technically right). I did not realise (but it seems obvious now) that pivot has an implicit grouping.

Comment: Update: I did the wrong thing when trying to remove the column. I now got it to work without the extra CTE layer from the other answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to `GROUP BY` in a step before you take the `DENSE_RANK()` since you aren't using the `WeekNum` in your `PIVOT` output.

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT Vehicle
                    ,datepart(week,recordedoneffective) as WeekNum                  
                    ,sum(totalweight ) AS TotalWeight
              FROM vw_visit_details v, vw_food_stats f
              WHERE v.VisitId = f.VisitId
                and recordedoneffective between '2015-01-05' and '2015-03-01'
              GROUP BY vehicle,   datepart(week,recordedoneffective)
              )
     ,cte2 AS (SELECT  vehicle 
                      ,dense_rank() OVER ( ORDER BY WeekNum ) AS WeekSeq 
                      ,TotalWeight
               FROM cte
               )
SELECT vehicle, [1] AS W1, [2] AS W2, [3] AS W3, [4] AS W4, [5] AS W5, [6] AS W6, [7] AS W7, [8] AS W8
FROM cte2
PIVOT (SUM(TotalWeight) FOR WeekSeq IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])) pvt
ORDER BY pvt.vehicle
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Note I had to change to `dense_rank OVER (ORDER BY WeekNum) AS WeekSeq` in `cte2` just to make the syntax valid (becauseits now a named column in `cte` rather than a calculated column in the current statement). I don't fully understand why the additional `GROUP BY` was required though - should not the extra unused column just be ignored?

Comment: @Visser The reasoning is probably easiest to understand if you include `WeekNum` in your original `SELECT` and run.